# what is the benefit of --squeeze-repeats in tr command

Tags: tr

What is the benefit of `-s` or `--squeeze-repeats` when we use `tr`? What practical usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU coreutils manual gives [some example applications](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Squeezing.html) such as collapsing multiple newlines into one (`tr -s '\n'`), or putting each word on its own line while removing punctuation at the same time (`tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]'`).

Answer (score 2):

[How to make the 'cut' command treat several sequential delimiters as one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one/4483833#4483833)

```
$ cat text.txt | tr -s " " " " | cut -d " " -f 4
```

Comment: `< text.txt tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 4` is shorter: it leaves out the unnecessary second argument to `tr` and the [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).